# react-native run-android getting error : A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.([androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01])

Tags: typescript, gradle, react-native

I have created a new project by using react-native init  but I'm getting the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/Users/vahiddavoudi/Project/BBW/android/app/build.gradle' line: 202

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
 **Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.**

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#andr
oid-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Versions:

- react: 16.9.0
- react-native: 0.61.1

**Note:** environment variables in bash_profile are setup.
I have also tried to remove node_module and run yarn but no success

Comment: maybe you should give some more detail like content of your android/app/build.gradle and android/build.gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `android/app/build.gradle`, use this in the dependencies:

```js
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
```